# Eclipse Remote Procedure Call

Tags: eclipse, rpc

Does eclipse have some sort of RPC hooks? or anything I could use to have an application requesting eclipse to add a specific class to the current project classpath or ask it to build the workspace? I absolutely don't want to use plugins, I need a solution that comes with eclipse by default

Comment: Eclipse does not have anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically no. There's nothing built-in for this.